# Issues while upgrading to plasma 5.4 in Kubuntu 15.04--freezes on boot

Tags: 15.04, kubuntu, kde, plasma-5

I have a fairly recent install of Kubuntu 15.04 that I upgraded to plasma 5.4. There were no errors on upgrading, but I noticed that it didn't fully upgrade. I didn't have the option of the new application window, the clock didn't organize horizontally, the network manager on the panel didn't show a graph, etc. So I downgraded back to plasma 5.2 with the intent of reinstalling 5.4. On the downgrade I got a couple of errors that said two packages couldn't be downgraded. I then reinstalled plasma 5.4 to get everything back to speed and now when I boot my computer freezes on the kubuntu flash screen.

Is there any way to reinstall the KDE environment completely fresh and what is the best way to do so?

Comment: You could try to reset Plasma by completely clearing its configuration, which is usually found in .kde ; .config/k*rc ; etcetera

Comment: I have installed Kubuntu 16.04 x64, and have the same NetworkManager issue, after some time, no graph is shown, neither traffic indicator. I can see the wifi connection, but when i start downloading something, the graph is not updated.